# Tower coordinates changing in collision method

Tags: c++, sfml, clock

I have two classes. one class is a monster class, and one class is a tower class. I am trying to detect collision. I store each class in a vector and draw them to the screen. However my collision function which just currently prints out my towersGetPosition().x prints my towers at 0. They are not 0,0 on the screen so I figured it had something to do with my update function.

```
void Game::update(sf::Time elapsed)
{
    if (elapsed.asSeconds() > 1.0f)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mymonsters.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < myicetower.size(); k++)
            {
                mymonsters[i].checkcolission(myicetower[k]);    
            }
        }
    }
}

void Game::run()
{
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time dt;
    sf::Time elapsed;
    elapsed = clock.getElapsedTime();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        elapsed = clock.getElapsedTime();
        processEvents();
        update(elapsed);
        render();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you handling their positions?  How are you drawing them? also your collisions wont start until you have had 1 second go by.  BTW, what is your update going to do with the elapsed time since the creation of your clock?  Normally you use a delta time for update.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's impossible to help you with your `checkcolission` method, when we have to guess what it is or does.

Comment: I'd bet the parameter for checkcolission is being copied, which would explain why it's always at 0,0.